# How do I add grades that are separated by "space" to a list box?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a text file, that i want to save it's content in different text boxes and the last part in a list box.

**Text file looks like this:** Jon Mayer,21,Romanian-American University,Photography,8 9 7 6(grades)

I created a structure named

```
public struct Student
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string university;
    public string hobby;
    public int grades;
}
```

I used a Streamreader to read all the text and split it where the ',' is as following:

```
bool CitesteStudent (out Student s, string fisier)
{
    s = new Student();
    if (!File.Exists(fisier)) return false;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fisier))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string str;
            string[] strArray;
            str = sr.ReadLine();
            strArray = str.Split(',');
            s.name = strArray[0];
            s.age = int.Parse(strArray[1]);
            s.university = strArray[2];
            s.hobby = strArray[3]
    }}
    return true;
}
```

I loaded the data in text boxes:

```
void IncarcareDate(Student s)
{
    txtBoxNume.Text = s.name;
    txtBoxVarsta.Text = Convert.ToString(s.age);
    txtBoxFacultate.Text = s.university;
    txtBoxHobby.Text = s.hobby;
}
```

if i do not include the grades and the list-box the program works. What can i do to add the grades in a list box(each grade to be on a single line of the list box).

Comment: Are you having trouble with parsing the grades, or with displaying a list?

Comment: Both of them... I tried different things but i can't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your class like this:

```
public struct Student
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public string university;
    public string hobby;
    //public int grades;
    public List<string> grades;
}
```

now you should be able to parse the grades to a list of grades:

```
bool CitesteStudent (out Student s, string fisier)
{
    s = new Student();
    if (!File.Exists(fisier)) return false;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fisier))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string str;
            string[] strArray;
            str = sr.ReadLine();
            strArray = str.Split(',');
            s.name = strArray[0];
            s.age = int.Parse(strArray[1]);
            s.university = strArray[2];
            s.hobby = strArray[3];
            // given string in strArray[4] should be: 8 9 7 6
            // we split the Whitespace
            // and transfer it to a List
            s.grades = strArray[4].Split(' ').ToList();
    }}
    return true;
}
```

To populate the list box try:

```
void IncarcareDate(Student s)
{
    txtBoxNume.Text = s.name;
    txtBoxVarsta.Text = Convert.ToString(s.age);
    txtBoxFacultate.Text = s.university;
    txtBoxHobby.Text = s.hobby;
    txtBoxGrades.Items.AddRange(s.grades.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: i tried what you said, the problem is whit loading the grades into the list box. I added  `listBox1.Text =Convert.ToString(s.grades);` where i transfer the data .

Comment: okay. i updated the answer. change the `List<int>` to a `List<string>`